# can openssl_pkcs7_verify accept a filepointer?

Tags: php, php-openssl

I'm using `openssl_pkcs7_verify()` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkcs7-verify.php) to verify a signed mail content with smime (p7s) information. This function is useful for my purpose, but i want to use it with content stored on memory wrappers (php://memory or php://temp), `openssl_pkcs7_verify()` accepts only filepaths as parameters and not filepointers (like ones i can get from a fopen('php://memory', ...) ), i tried to use this code:

```
  $filep = fopen('php://memory', 'wb+');
  $file_metadata = stream_get_meta_data($filep);
  $filename = $file_metadata["uri"];
  openssl_pkcs7_verify($filename, PKCS7_NOVERIFY, $filename)
```

but obviously  `$filename` contains `php://memory`, and not particular reference to memory related to `fopen` call (not to memory referenced by `$filep`), so code generates an error about `openssl_pkcs7_verify()` is unable to write on path passed on parameter 3.
It forces me to use a temp file, but could be a great improvement use in memory content and not file content, avoiding I/O latency and other issues.